# What are the fields for the default express console output?

Tags: express, logging, express-generator

When you start a an express server using express-generator you get a single-line output for each request that looks a bit like this

```
GET /images/07777c4bc2aebaff6964a46b7c3714f3.png 200 2.730 ms - 15919
```

What are the space delimited fields?
The first 4 are self evident, but the last 2 aren't.

- http verb
- endpoint
- http status
- number of ms required to generate and send the response
- ?
- ?

Comment: Did you look at what's actually configured to generate them? I'd guess https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan#dev

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what is generating them. I looked at www, but I see where you are pointing. let me see what the App is .use() ing and go from there...

Answer (score 0):

I found it. Turns out the express-generator generates the following code

```
const logger = require( "morgan" );
app.use( logger( "dev" ) );
```

In other words, express uses `morgan` as its default logger. It puts `morgan` in `dev` mode. When `morgan` is in `dev` mode it generates the following fields

```
:method :url :status :response-time ms - :res[content-length]
```

[Documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan#dev)

Comment: It might be helpful to include what's actually in the generated code, and/or https://github.com/expressjs/generator/blob/d1f3fcc6ccc7ab8986fb3438c82ab1a1f20dc50d/bin/express-cli.js#L166-L169 that's used to generate it.

Comment: i agree. updated the answer to reflect such